# ASP.NET MVC route by a city then controller and action

Tags: routes, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a basic ASP.NET MVC5 app with a Restaurant class as my model and I am currently using the default out of the box routing.

- /Restaurant/Create
- /Restaurant/Details
- /Restaurant/Index

Previously this was only based on one city. Now I would like to make this multi city and route it in such a way

- London/Restaurant/Index
- Manchester/Restaurant/Index
- Birmingham/Restaurant/Index

I've been reading up on custom routing in ASP.NET, attribute routing, routing constraints but I cannot figure out how to achieve the above.

I tried changing the default route in RouteConfig.cs to the following but this does not work.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{city}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Here is my Restaurant Controller Index signature

```
        public ActionResult Index(int? RestaurantId)
        {
            ViewBag.Restaurants = new SelectList(db.Restaurants.ToList().OrderBy(r => r.RestaurantName), "RestaurantID", "RestaurantName");

            return View(db.Restaurants.ToList());
        }
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? You get a 404?  Could you add signature of Restaurant/Index controller action please, also if there are any routes above "Default" in your RouteConfig pls

Comment: @dove So sorry I forgot to reply! Yes I get a 404.

Comment: Added controller signature above now, there were no other routes apart from the default one.

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of anyone reading this post in the future:I found a different way to achieve my goal of using cities. I read up on subdomains and found that I could use:

- `london.mydomain.com`
- `manchester.mydomain.com`
- `birmingham.mydomain.com`

This is by using a custom `RouteBase` class as described in this interesting [article](https://bencull.com/blog/subdomain-routing-in-asp-net-mvc).